# Reading a JSON string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, asihttprequest

I have a JSON String, in the format;

```
{
    "name": "Alex",
    "age": "12"
}
```

I know how to extract values from the above JSON. but at times, when there are no records in the database. i get a `null` value printed. (i undestand that this is not a valid JSON)

This `null` gets caught in the following if-condition.

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [SBJsonParser new];              
       NSDictionary *content = [pobjectWithString:[request responseString]];       
       if(!content){       
           NSLog(@" when its null it comes to this block");
           return;
       }
```

I need to read this value `null` and save it in a NSString. How can i do this ?

note: i have made use of ASIHTTPRequest to write the above code.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking for, if there is no record, you receive no information (ergo nil or null), what's wrong with that?

Comment: That code doesn't even look like it is parsing the JSON string. Usually SBJSON has a method that takes an NSString and returns a dictionary of values.

Comment: @JiaYow I need to save the string `null` which is returned by the web service to a NSString. how can i do that. in order to save the string `null` to a NSString i will have to read this value and then store it. Can someone help me do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're asking for.  I think you want to detect when a null occurs (which you already seem to do with if(!content) ), then you want to create a string that either is empty, or has the word "null" in it.  Why not:

```
if(!content) {
  return @"null";
}
```

Of course, you could return whatever you wanted in the string.

Comment: Be careful when you do that though, it's generally not a good idea because you might not know if @"null" was the actual correct result (like some guy named "Null") or the result of an error

Comment: No, i need to store the `null` which is returned from the web service to be stored in a NSString. note: The web service only returns the string `null`

Comment: What's the difference between storing the string "null" in an NSString, and creating an NSString that has the word "null" in it?  If it's null, why does it matter that it came from the web service?  It's still null.